# Method To Return a List of Recommendations to the User

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created the db and tables and a model classes of each table having the same properties as column name.
How do i create a method in controller class [Asp.Net MVC] to return a list of recommendation of music to the user i.e the musics that are in the library of users friends.
Each user has a list of music tracks in their library and each user has a list of friends(Users). Recommendations are all the music tracks, which are owned by the user’s immediate friends but not by the user.
Similary using a MusicInfoDBContext class and `Dbsets: public DbSet<Users> Users{ get; set; }`
Following is the signature of the method:

```
List<Music> getMusicRecommendations(User user);
```

and the DBScript is as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE OnlineMusicStore
    CREATE TABLE Users(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    Username nvarchar(255)
    )

    CREATE TABLE Music
    (
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    MusicName nvarchar(255),
    )

    CREATE TABLE Users_Music
    (
    UserId int foreign key references Users(ID),
    MusicId int foreign key references Music(ID)
    )

    CREATE TABLE Users_Friends
    (
    UserId int foreign key references Users(ID),
    FriendId int foreign key references Users(ID)
    )
 public class Users
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
  public class Music
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string MusicName { get; set; }
    }
 public class Users_Music
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int MusicId { get; set; }
    }
  public class Users_Friends
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int FriendId { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone elaborate the solution as i can understand it better.
One of my Friend suggested using:

```
recommendations = AllFriendsMusicList.Except(user.MusicList)
```

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code:

```
user.friends.selectall(friend->friend.musics).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

To break it down into each component

You can get the ID's of the users immediate friends with

```
IEnumerable<int> friendIDs = db.Users_Friends
    .Where(u => u.UserId == user.ID)
    .Select(u => u.FriendId);
```

Then you can then get the ID's of all those friends music with

```
IEnumerable<int> musicIDs = db.Users_Music
    .Where(m => friendIDs.Contains(m.UserId))
    .Select(m => m.MusicId);
```

And finally get all the music objects with

```
IEnumerable<Music> model = db.Music
    .Where(m => musicIDs.Contains(m.ID));
```

or if you need `List<Music>`, then add `ToList()` to the above

So you method becomes

```
public List<Music> getMusicRecommendations(User user)
{
    IEnumerable<int> friendIDs = db.Users_Friends.Where(u => u.UserId == user.ID).Select(u => u.FriendId);
    IEnumerable<int> musicIDs = db.Users_Music.Where(m => friendIDs.Contains(m.UserId)).Select(m => m.MusicId);
    return db.Music.Where(m => musicIDs.Contains(m.ID)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Is My Database Design alright, and can i implement the above code in a single method?

Comment: I don't know enough about your app to comment on whether the design is the best for you. And since your classes do not include navigation properties (`public virtual User ...` etc) I doubt you can do this in a single statement (which is what I assume you mean since all this goes inside `getMusicRecommendations(User user){ ... return model;}` it is a single method) but I'll have a think about it).

Comment: I don't see any better way of doing it than I have suggested. And I have updated the answer to show the full method.

Comment: Can i include all the above code within the index method of Some controller.

Comment: You could, but why? It should ideally a method (preferably in a service) so that you can call it anywhere. And even better, that service should be injected into the Controller.

Comment: In your above solution IEnumerable<int> friendIDs = db.Users_Friends
    .Where(u => u.UserId == user.ID)
    .Select(u => u.FriendId) user is not instantiated, So can i include a instance of class User as user above it as: User user=new User(); is it okay?

Comment: What do you mean _not instantiated_? Your method `getMusicRecommendations(User user)` has a parameter which is typeof `User`, so when you call the method you pass it an instance of the current user (no point using `User user=new User();` because `user.ID would be zero and no records would ever be returned).

Comment: or can i do like this? `      public ActionResult Index()
        {

getMusicRecommendations();
        }`

Comment: And you don't really even need to pass it an instance of `User` - it could be `getMusicRecommendations(int userID)` and you pass it the ID of the current user.

Comment: I'm guessing now that your completely new to this. The `Index()` method would be something like - `public ActionResult Index() { var userID = someValue; var model = getMusicRecommendations(userID); return View(model); }` assuming you change the signature from `User user` to `int userID` as per my previous comment, and that the method is in the same controller.

Comment: I mean at the first  get the ID's of the users immediate friends: `IEnumerable<int> friendIDs = db.Users_Friends
    .Where(u => u.UserId == user.ID)
    .Select(u => u.FriendId);`  I mean the `user` at this code.

Comment: No my signature should be as previously i stated.

Comment: OMG. I repeat again - your method signature is `getMusicRecommendations(User user)` - you need to **pass** a value for `user` to the method. In the `Index()` method you need `var user = // here you get the current user; var model = getMusicRecommendations(user); return View(model);`

Comment: Yeah, i understand. Many Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: How can i calculate the time complexity i.e Big O Notation of the above method?